# How can I make the WP Publicize plugin share my posts to (all or specific) Google+ circles?

Tags: google-plus, wordpress

I use Wordpress, and I'm trying to use the Publicize plugin to auto-post new blog posts to my Google+ circles. However, when I publish a Wordpress post, the plugin correctly picks it up and puts it in my "posts" stream on Google+, but the post is shared privately only with myself.

To really share it, I'd have to re-share my own post, and that looks silly so in the end I post it manually. But that's really what the plugin should be doing for me.

I'd expect some place where I can choose what circles should be used by Publicize to publish my posts on Google+, but I can't find that.

- I've reviewed the plugin settings but didn't find anything related to G+ circles.
- I've also reviewed my Google Account security settings, specifically the account permissions for Wordpress that is listed, but there's no setting I can change (except revoking the account permission entirely).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found it myself. WP lists this very promising [page about Publicize](http://jetpack.me/support/publicize/google/) and it says to open Google+ (in a browser, not smartphone!) and then go to **Settings > Manage apps & activities**.

I'm on mobile now so I'll check this from home and confirm.
**update:** Yes, this is how to change the audience for new WP posts. The circle choices are:

- Public
- extended circles
- your circles
- your organization (if you're a Google Apps user)
- only you
- **custom** (this is where you can specify any mix of circles you like)

[image]